# Python: Reading part of a text file

Tags: python

HI all

I'm new to python and programming. I need to read in chunks of a large text file, format looks like the following:

```
<word id="8" form="hibernis" lemma="hibernus1" postag="n-p---nb-" head-"7" relation="ADV"/>
```

I need the `form`, `lemma` and `postag` information. e.g. for above I need `hibernis`, `hibernus1` and `n-p---nb-`.

How do I tell python to read until it reaches form, to read forward until it reaches the quote mark `"` and then read the information between the quote marks `"hibernis"`? Really struggling with this.

My attempts so far have been to remove the punctuation, split the sentence and then pull the info I need from a list. Having trouble getting python to iterate over whole file though, I can only get this working for 1 line. My code is below:

```
f=open('blank.txt','r')
quotes=f.read()
noquotes=quotes.replace('"','')
f.close()

rf=open('blank.txt','w')
rf.write(noquotes)
rf.close()   

f=open('blank.txt','r')
finished = False
postag=[]
while not finished:
   line=f.readline()
   words=line.split()
   postag.append(words[4])
   postag.append(words[6])
   postag.append(words[8])              
   finished=True
```

Would appreciate any feedback/criticisms

thanks

Answer (score 5):

If it's XML, use [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) to parse it:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

line = '<word id="8" form="hibernis" lemma="hibernus1" postag="n-p---nb-" head="7" relation="ADV"/>'

element = ElementTree.fromstring(line)
```

For each XML element you can easily extract the name and all the attributes:

```
>>> element.tag
'word'
>>> element.attrib
{'head': '7', 'form': 'hibernis', 'postag': 'n-p---nb-', 'lemma': 'hibernus1', 'relation': 'ADV', 'id': '8'}
```

So if you have a document with a bunch of `word` XML elements, something like this will extract the information you want from each one:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

XML = '''
<words>
    <word id="8" form="hibernis" lemma="hibernus1" postag="n-p---nb-" head="7" relation="ADV"/>
</words>'''

root = ElementTree.fromstring(XML)

for element in root.findall('word'):
    form = element.attrib['form']
    lemma = element.attrib['lemma']
    postag = element.attrib['postag']

    print form, lemma, postag
```

Use `parse()` instead of `fromstring()` if you only have a filename.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using the regular expression module: [re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)

Something along these lines perhaps?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = open('x').read()
    RE = re.compile('.*form="(.*)" lemma="(.*)" postag="(.*?)"', re.M)
    matches = RE.findall(data)
    for m in matches:
        print m
```

This does assume that the `<word ...>` lines are each on a single line and that each part is in that exact order, and that you don't need to deal with full xml parsing.

Comment: Thanks retracile. Just tried your code and its exactly what i need. Really appreciate your help. I did try the re module at first and had the following expression:
for line in f:
       if re.match("(.*)(f|1)orm(.*)", line):
              print >>rfformat, line,

Comment: but stupidly gave up on that method and went for the list method.
i'm now going to study the re module and make sure i know what your code is doing

Comment: The regex (and mine below) makes an assumption, though, about ordering of the tags, which may not be valid for all entries

Comment: It is very rarely a good idea to parse XML with regular expressions.  For instance, this RE will fail if the attributes are delimited with single quotes, and it won't expand character entities in the text, which the application probably needs it to.

Comment: If your problem is to read XML and you try to use regex, now you have 3 problems: the original, trying to force regex to solve it, and not even knowing you're on the wrong path.

Answer (score 1):

Is your file proper XML?  If so, try a SAX parser:

```
import xml.sax
class Handler (xml.sax.ContentHandler):
   def startElement (self, tag, attrs):
       if tag == 'word':
           print 'form=', attrs['form']
           print 'lemma=',attrs['lemma']
           print 'postag=',attrs['postag']

ch = Handler ()
f = open ('myfile')
xml.sax.parse (f, ch)
```

(this is rough .. it may not be entirely correct).

Comment: hi there, file is all xml, will have to look sax parser up and also beautiful soup mentioned below. Will prob make things a lot simpler. thanks for your help

Comment: just remember that BeautifulSoup is not part on the standard python distribution (in case you ever have to use this script in environments where you don't have permission to add packages).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the usual RegEx answer, since this appears to be a form of XML, you might try something like BeautifulSoup ( http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/ )

It's very easy to use, and find tags/attributes in things like HTML/XML, even if they're not "well formed". Might be worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing xml by hand is usually the
   wrong thing. For one thing, your code
   will break if there's an escaped
   quote in any of the attributes.
   Getting the attributes from an xml
   parser is probably cleaner and less
   error-prone.

An approach like this can also run into problems parsing the entire file if you have lines that don't match the format. You can deal with this either by creating a parseline method (something like

```
def parse (line):
      try: 
          return parsed values here
        except:
```

You can also simplify this with filter and map functions:

```
lines = filter( lambda line: parseable(line), f.readlines())
values = map (parse, lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to highlight your problem:

```
finished = False
counter = 0
while not finished:
   counter += 1
   finished=True
print counter
```

Comment: in fact, your answer is the best. :) All others didn't care to correct the code.

Answer (score 0):

With regular expressions, this is the gist (you can do the file.readline() part):

```
import re
line = '<word id="8" form="hibernis" lemma="hibernus1" postag="n-p---nb-" head-"7" relation="ADV"/>'
r = re.compile( 'form="([^"]*)".*lemma="([^"]*)".*postag="([^"]*)"' )
match = r.search( line )
print match.groups()

>>> 
('hibernis', 'hibernus1', 'n-p---nb-')
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, don't spend a lot of time rewriting your file.  It's generally a waste of time.  The processing to clean up and parse the tags is so fast, that you'll be perfectly happy working from the source file all the time.

```
source= open( "blank.txt", "r" )
for line in source:
    # line has a tag-line structure
    # <word id="8" form="hibernis" lemma="hibernus1" postag="n-p---nb-" head-"7" relation="ADV"/>
    # Assumption -- no spaces in the quoted strings.
    parts = line.split()
    # parts is [ '<word', 'id="8"', 'form="hibernis"', ... ]
    assert parts[0] == "<word"
    nameValueList = [ part.partition('=') for part in parts[1:] ]
    # nameValueList is [ ('id','=','"8"'), ('form','=','"hibernis"'), ... ]
    attrs = dict( (n,eval(v)) for n, _, v in nameValueList )
    # attrs is { 'id':'8', 'form':'hibernis', ... }
    print attrs['form'], attrs['lemma'], attrs['posttag']
```

Comment: is there a really need for eval here? wouldn't strip('"') be a better option?

Comment: @SilentGhost: this is one of those six of one, half a dozen of the other situations.  Some folks like to say "eval is evil" -- which is largely senseless.  However, it's also a coincidence that the string shown in the example appears to be a valid Python string.  Perhaps there are escape characters are different from Python, making eval invalid because of non-python string syntax.

Answer (score 0):

wow, you guys are fast :)
If you want all attributes of a list (and the ordering is known), then you can use something like this:

```
import re
print re.findall('"(.+?)"',INPUT)
```

INPUT is a line like:

```
<word id="8" form="hibernis" lemma="hibernus1" postag="n-p---nb-" head="7" relation="ADV"/>
```

and the printed list is:

```
['8', 'hibernis', 'hibernus1', 'n-p---nb-', '7', 'ADV']
```