# successively take values between two sub-strings and temporarily store it before writing them in a different order withhin a python fileread

Tags: python, file-io, kml, gpx

I am reading the body of a .gpx file and need to change the format of the data so it can be read as a .kml

.kml has `lat` and `long` in a swapped order from .gpx, **so i need to find a way to successively take values between two sub-strings and temporarily store it before writing them in a different order**. .kml also separates `<time>` from `<coords>` but that is pretty much the same type of task.

I have looked at many resources including:

- [Python: Reading part of a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964993/python-reading-part-of-a-text-file) but i'm not just after one value, i need it for LOTS of data points.
- i also tried ElementTree. but couldn't get it to fly

i tried

```
lat = re.search('<trkpt lat="(.*)" lon="', x)
lon = re.search('" lon="(.*)">', x)
```

which obviously doesnt work for multiple values in the original file.  my code probably isn't very pythonic (yet). The code:

```
def convert(fileName):
    f = open(fileName, "r")
    x = f.read()                
    x = re.sub(r'<trkpt lat="', '           <gx:coord>', x)
    x = re.sub(r'" lon="', ' ', x)
    x = re.sub(r'"><ele>', ' ', x)
    x = re.sub(r'</ele>', '</gx:coord>\n', x)
    x = re.sub(r'<speed>.*?</speed>', '', x)
    return x
```

is getting me close to a format of whats needed. But i can't work out how to successively pass the multiple values, swap them around a bit and progressively re-write

i'm new to python....please send help.  thanks!

*EDIT*

examples of each file type follows (for clarity i have taken off the header text of each)

.gpx looks like this and has time and coordinates concurrent. As you can see, each data point exists between `<trkpt` and `</trkpt>` (.gpx also has speed and sometimes other stuff that needs cleaning out too):

`<trkseg>
<trkpt lat="-33.8598" lon="151.17912"><ele>7.8</ele><speed>0.9013878</speed><time>2012-09-25T07:38:42Z</time></trkpt><trkpt lat="-33.859936" lon="151.17906"><ele>20.8</ele><speed>2.25</speed><time>2012-09-25T07:38:43Z</time></trkpt><trkpt lat="-33.859818" lon="151.17934"><ele>-3.4</ele><speed>1.5</speed><time>2012-09-25T07:38:45Z</time></trkpt>
<trkpt lat="-33.859947" lon="151.17914"><ele>16.2</ele><speed>1.5</speed><time>2012-09-25T07:38:49Z</time></trkpt><trkpt lat="-33.860016" lon="151.1792"><ele>18.0</ele><speed>1.75</speed><time>2012-09-25T07:38:52Z</time></trkpt><trkpt lat="-33.86008" lon="151.17923"><ele>18.4</ele><speed>1.5811388</speed><time>2012-09-25T07:38:57Z</time></trkpt><trkpt lat="-33.86013" lon="151.17932"><ele>18.1</ele><speed>1.75</speed><time>2012-09-25T07:39:03Z</time></trkpt>`

OK....and this is the equivalent .kml which separates `<when>` from the coordinates`<gx:coords>`. of course there is always the same number of each. you can see the elevation (`<ele>` in the .gpx) is an untagged number in coords after the position data.

`

```
        <when>2012-09-25T07:38:42Z</when>
        <when>2012-09-25T07:38:43Z</when>
        <when>2012-09-25T07:38:45Z</when>
        <when>2012-09-25T07:38:49Z</when>
        <when>2012-09-25T07:38:52Z</when>
        <when>2012-09-25T07:38:57Z</when>
        <when>2012-09-25T07:39:03Z</when>
        <gx:coord>151.17912 -33.8598 7.8</gx:coord>
        <gx:coord>151.17906 -33.859936 20.8</gx:coord>
        <gx:coord>151.17934 -33.859818 -3.4</gx:coord>
        <gx:coord>151.17914 -33.859947 16.2</gx:coord>
        <gx:coord>151.1792 -33.860016 18</gx:coord>
        <gx:coord>151.17923 -33.86008 18.4</gx:coord>
        <gx:coord>151.17932 -33.86013 18.1</gx:coord>
```

`

Comment: note: the order of lat and long in .kml is important to get right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working but is SLOW. for a small .gpx of 477k, it is writing a .kml of 207k that takes 198 seconds to complete.  my hunch is that it is the `stringIO.stringIO(x)` that's so slow. any ideas how to speed it up would be fantastic.

Here are the key snips ONLY of what i have done:

```
f = open(fileName, "r")
x = f.read()
x = re.sub(r'\n', '', x, re.S) #remove any newline returns
name = re.search('<name>(.*)</name>', x, re.S)
print "Attachment name (as recorded from GPS device): " + name.group(1)

x = re.sub(r'<(.*)<trkseg>', '', x, re.S)  #strip header
x = x.replace("</trkseg></trk></gpx>",""); #strip footer
x = x.replace("<trkpt","\n<trkpt"); #make the file in lines
x = re.sub(r'<speed>(.*?)</speed>', '', x, re.S) #strip speed
x = re.sub(r'<extensions>(.*?)</extensions>', '', x, re.S) # strip out extensions
```

then

```
#.kml header goes here
kmlTrack = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><kml xmlns="http://www.ope......etc etc
```

then

```
buf = StringIO.StringIO(x)
for line in buf:
            if line is not None:
                    timm = re.search('time>(.*?)</time', line, re.S)
                    if timm is not None:
                            kmlTrack += ("          <when>"+ timm.group(1)+"</when>\n")
                            checkSumA =+ 1
buf = StringIO.StringIO(x)
for line in buf:
            if line is not None:
                    lat = re.search('lat="(.*?)" lo', line, re.S)
                    lon = re.search('lon="(.*?)"><ele>', line, re.S)
                    ele = re.search('<ele>(.*?)</ele>', line, re.S)
                    if lat is not None:
                            kmlTrack += ("          <gx:coord>"+ lon.group(1) + " " + lat.group(1) + " " + ele.group(1) + "</gx:coord>\n")
                            checkSumB =+ 1
if checkSumA == checkSumB:
            #put a footer on
            kmlTrack += """     </gx:Track></Placemark></Document></kml>"""
else:
            print ("checksum error")
            return None

with open("Realbush2.kml", "a") as myfile:
            myfile.write(kmlTrack)
return ("succsesful .kml file-write completed in :" + str(c.seconds) + " seconds.")
```

Once again, this is working but it is **very slow**. If anyone can see how to speed this up, please let me know! Thanks